# How to return specific text from node in XML file?

Tags: xml, xpath, groovy, xml-parsing

I'm trying to return values from XML by parsing text. 
I've got one to work where I look for a specific value, and then return the text in a specific element below.

However, I can't get it to work when I want to return text from an attritube instead an element.

Here you can see an example of what the XML document looks like:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ADI3 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Asset xsi:type="offer:OfferType" uriId="url.com/assetID">
      <offer:BillingId>DUMMY</offer:BillingId>
   </Asset>
   <Asset xsi:type="title:TitleType">
      <core:Description deprecated="true" xmlns:core="urn:cablelabs:md:xsd:core:3.0">Title Package</core:Description>
      <core:Ext xsi:type="ExtType" xmlns:core="urn:cablelabs:md:xsd:core:3.0">
         <TestipediaInfo>
            <test:SeriesInfo xml:lang="en" seasonNumber="2" episodeNumber="9">
               <test:SeriesBrief>A very nice title</test:SeriesBrief>
               <test:EpisodeInfo>
                  <test:SummaryShort>Peter and the crew travel to Greenland.</test:SummaryShort>
               </test:EpisodeInfo>
            </test:SeriesInfo>
         </TestipediaInfo>
      </core:Ext>
   </Asset>
   <Asset xsi:type="offer:OfferType" uriId="url.com/assetID">
      <core:Description deprecated="true" xmlns:core="urn:cablelabs:md:xsd:core:3.0">Series Poster</core:Description>
      <content:SourceUrl>A-typical-file-name_1000x1500.jpg</content:SourceUrl>
   </Asset>
</ADI3>
```

and I use this groovy code:

```
File file = new File("stackoverflowtest.xml")

def str = file.text

def xmlSlurper = new XmlSlurper(false,false)
def root = xmlSlurper.parseText(str)
def path = 'Asset."core:Ext".TestipediaInfo."test:SeriesInfo".find{it.@"xml:lang" == "en"}."test:EpisodeInfo"."test:SummaryShort"'
def xpathRes = Eval.x(root, "x.$path")

print(xpathRes)
```

which prints the value from test:SummaryShort

However, I want to be able to do a similar xPath (like `'Asset."core:Ext".TestipediaInfo."test:SeriesInfo".find{it.@"xml:lang" == "en"}."test:EpisodeInfo"."test:SummaryShort"'` to return the text from `<content:SourceUrl>` when `<core:Description deprecated="true" xmlns:core="urn:cablelabs:md:xsd:core:3.0">Series Poster</core:Description>`contains "Series Poster".

Comment: Have you tried with `'Asset."core:Description".find{it.@"." == "Series Poster"}."content:SourceUrl"`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using `eval`...

You should just be able to run:

```
root.Asset.findAll { it.'core:Description'.@deprecated == 'true' }.'content:SourceUrl'*.text()
```

To return a list containing all the SourceUrl text for any node which has deprecated true as an attribute of Description